# how to add object in Arraylist which contains matched items only java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two Arraylist one List that is ShoppingList which contains item such as [tea,milk,sugar]

and another List which is my Recipe object ingredients list...So how to add  object only in a result list which contains these items ?
The problem is that its add multiple object with contains these items
My code which finds common items in both list :

```
    final List<RecipeN> result = new ArrayList<RecipeN>();
        for (RecipeN rn : allrec) {
            for (ShoppingList sl : allitems) {
                for(int i = 0;i<rn.getIngredient().size();i++) {
                    if (rn.getIngredients(i).contains(sl.getrName())) {
                        result.add(rn);
                    }
                }
            }





public class RecipeN {
    private String recName;
    private List<String> ingredient = new ArrayList<String>();

    public RecipeN(){

    }
    public RecipeN(String item){
        this.ingredient.add(item);
    }

    public List<String> getIngredient(){
        return ingredient;
    }
    public String getIngredients(int i){

        return ingredient.get(i);
    }
    public void setIngredient(List<String> item){
        this.ingredient = item;
    }

    public String getRecName() {
        return recName;
    }

    public void setRecName(String recName) {
        this.recName = recName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return recName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method `retainAll(Collection c)` to only keep the items in a shopping list that appears in a recipe. Code example is as below:

```
List<Item> recipe = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();

... your code ...

shoppingList.retainAll(recipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only 1 times each match recipe you should use a `HashSet` in order to not have duplicate in the list.

```
final Set<RecipeN> result = new HashSet<RecipeN>();
for (RecipeN rn : allrec) {
    for (ShoppingList sl : allitems) {
        for(int i = 0;i<rn.getIngredient().size();i++) {
           if (rn.getIngredients(i).contains(sl.getrName())) {
                result.add(rn);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to keep an ArrayList you can do that :

```
final Set<RecipeN> result = new HashSet<RecipeN>();
for (RecipeN rn : allrec) {
    boolean recipeMatched = false;
    for (ShoppingList sl : allitems) {
        for(int i = 0;i<rn.getIngredient().size();i++) {
           if (rn.getIngredients(i).contains(sl.getrName())) {
                recipeMatched = true;
                result.add(rn);
                break;
           }
           if (recipeMatched)
               break;
        }
        if (recipeMatched)
           break;
    }
}
```